# In js how to calculate a date is greater than 24 hours in a array of object

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have array of object

objData = [ {Name : "oppName" , closedDate:"2022-04-02"} , { Name: "opoName1", closedDate: "2022-04-12"}]

I need to loop this objData to find if clsoedDate is greater than 24 hours then I need to append a property to that row with show = true and if closedDate is not greater than 24 hours then show should be set to false.

My final array will be in this format

objData = [ {Name : "oppName" , closedDate:"2022-04-02", show: "false"} , { Name: "opoName1", closedDate: "2022-04-12" , show:"true"}]

Comment: There are multiple ways to step through an array - see e.g. [JavaScript Array Iteration](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp) - and you can just set a property as JS does not use locked down types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're using `true` and `false`, rather than `"true"` and `"false"`; `"false"` is actually a [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.

Aside from that, calculating this is as simple as something like:

```
let today = new Date();
objData = objData.map(
  (record) => {
    let diff = new Date(record.closedDate) - today;
    return { ...record, show: diff > 8.64e7 }; // More than 86,400,000 milliseconds left
  }
);
```

Comment: Earlier the objData doesn't had a property called show.  Will it add property when you return{...record,  show: diff>8.64e7 } .   Well by the way,  what does ...record means?  What is ... Used for?

Comment: @Astriopa `...` is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). We use this to copy the record to a new object with all the same properties. We do this because records we get from Apex methods are typically readonly, so we need to clone the object first. The [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function copies an Array while transforming the data. As such, the show property will be present in the new Array.